# R system2 fails to exit after success

Tags: r, system2

I am running an external executable, capturing the result as an object. The .exe is a tool for selection of a population based on genetic parameters and genetic value predictions. The program executes and writes output as requested, but fails to exit. There is no error and when there is a manual stop it exits with status code 0. How can I get this call to exit and continue as it might with other system calls?

The call is formatted as seen below:

t <- tryCatch(system2("OPSEL.exe", args = "CMD.txt", timeout = 10))

I've tried running this in command shell with the two files referenced above and it exits appropriately.